# How to update Inner Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Hi I am having an issue with radio and checkbox on flutter. I have created my own widget on the purpose of having different return widget depending on what is needed as on the picture bellow since I selected change pin the return will be a checkbox but the return widget is a checkbox while the save button is stagnant or didn't change but I am having an issue when i used radio or check box even Visibility. When I try to update the setState() it is not updating or reloading the widget. The code below is just the first return of the widget which will be a check box. When i try to unchecked the button the value becomes falls but the UI is not unchecked.

[sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWQGq.png)

```
Widget getInputType(val){
    if(val == 'Pin Lock'){
    return CheckboxListTile(
        title: Text('Pin Login'),
        value: isSwitchPin,
        onChanged: (value){
        setState(() {
          print(value);
          this.isSwitchPin = value;
        });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1, Define a field

```
ValueChanged<bool> onEnventChange;
```

2, On initState()

```
onEnventChange = (value){
    setState(() {
      print(value);
      this.isSwitchPin = value;
    });
});
```

3, Define your function

```
Widget getInputType(val){
  if(val == 'Pin Lock'){
    return CheckboxListTile(
        title: Text('Pin Login'),
        value: isSwitchPin,
        onChanged: onEnventChange);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but the Checkbox become grey and unclickable

Comment: i tried and run ok. you can share me your code screenshot ?

Comment: I can't add screenshot on comment

Comment: You can try for me:  put init _onPinStatusChange_ on _initState_ to bellow _super.initState() _ ?

Comment: I didn't understand

Comment: "but the Checkbox become grey and unclickable" -> I think function get Widget call when onPinStatusChange not created.

Comment: I tried restarting the app now its clickable but it is still not updating. It only updates when I close the dialog and open it again

Comment: If it in dialog, you must define a widget for Dialog and update state in that Widget and pop result for before screen.

Comment: Yes it is a child inside alert dialog.

Comment: https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/05/hint-5-how-to-refresh-the-content-of-a-dialog-via-setstate/
you can try it.